# Acivity1 Fragment2 -> Activity2 (after button click) -> Activity1 Fragment2 navigate from activity to specific fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

Hello I have an application that implements bottom navigation component.

There is a main activity with 2 fragments (home fragment, note fragment).

I am going from **note fragment** to another activity called **AddNoteActivity**.

After I click a button in the AddNoteActivity I want the screen to show the main activity with the note fragment.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I understand that this code will launch the main activity but it automatically loads the home fragment because of its set as the `app:startDestination` in moblie_navigation.xml.

How would I get the main activity to load up the note fragment upon button click in the AddNoteActivity?

Also I have an action bar with up on navigation enabled. When I click the up arrow, I go back to the note fragment like its supposed to.

Comment: why don't you `finish();` after jobs done in ""AddNoteActivity""? and get data again  `resume()` in ""note fragment ""

Comment: that works perfectly, wow thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For go to the fragment just write**

on your button click {

finish();

}